# Matrix equation with inverse, left-multiply vs right-multiply -- does the sequence matter?

Tags: matrix-equations

Suppose I have a matrix equation of the form:
$$
C = ((A+X)^{-1}+B)^{-1}\tag{1}
$$
where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all squares and I want to solve for the unknown square $X$. (All of them are of the same dimension, $n$-by-$n$.)

Now, assume such an $X$ exists.
Then I see a number of ways to proceed.
First, I can *left*-multiply both sides of (1) by $(A+X)^{-1}+B$, getting
$((A+X)^{-1}+B)C = I$,
where $I$ is the identity matrix of the appropriate size.
Left-multiplying both sides by $A+X$ yields $(I + (A+X)B)C = A +X$, which after rearranging gives an expression of
$$X = (C - A + ABC)(I - BC)^{-1},\tag{2}$$
assuming $I - BC$ is invertible.

Second, I can instead *right*-multiply both sides of (1) by $(A+X)^{-1}+B$, getting $C((A+X)^{-1}+B)=I$.
Further right-multiplying both sides by $A+X$ yields $C(I+B(A+X))=A+X$, which gives another expression of
$$X = (I - CB)^{-1}(C - A + CBA),\tag{3}$$
assuming $I - CB$ is invertible.

Yet another approach is to let $Z=(A+X)^{-1}$, converting (1) into $C = (Z + B)^{-1}$, which yields $Z = C^{-1} - B$, assuming $C$ is invertible.
Then it follows that
$$X = (C^{-1} - B)^{-1} - A\tag{4}.$$

So it seems that I have recovered three different solutions of the original problem of (1).
In particular, the solutions (2)-(4) all seem to be *necessary* outcomes following (1), assuming the invertibility of $I-BC$, of $I-CB$, and of $C$.

However, in the numerical experiments I've tried, I can always reject (2).
For example,
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&3\end{bmatrix},\;
B = \begin{bmatrix}0&3\\-1&2\end{bmatrix},\;\text{and}\;
C = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
which satisfy the invertibility assumptions.
In this example, both (3) and (4) yield the same $X = \begin{bmatrix}-1.5&-0.5\\-0.5&-2.5\end{bmatrix}$, indeed solving (1), but the solution implied by (2) fails.

My question, in summary, is:
In which steps of the above did I mess up with the necessity, especially in deriving the expression (2)?
(This is particularly curious to me as the difference between (2) and (3) is only the left-multiplication vs. the right-multiplication.)

To clarify, I am not explicitly asking for all the solutions to (1).
I simply want to understand what went wrong above in deriving (2).
But of course, it would be nice to know further:
why (3) and (4) are equivalent numerically, even though they seem very different; and
whether (3) or (4) is the unique solution to (1).